# Pre-commit hook throws error on hatchling requirement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I'm following the [pre-commit directions](https://pre-commit.com/) to install git pre-commit hooks for python code formatting from [black](https://github.com/psf/black) to my flask repo. I've added `pre-commit` to my `requirements.txt` and my `pre-commit-config.yaml` file looks like

```yaml
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v2.3.0
    hooks:
      - id: check-yaml
      - id: end-of-file-fixer
      - id: trailing-whitespace
  - repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 22.12.0
    hooks:
      - id: black
```

After installing `pre-commit` using `pip install pre-commit` and installing the git hook scripts using `pre-commit install`, I get this error message related to a `hatchling` dependency package when making a git commit using `git commit`.

```bash
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/psf/black.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/Users/vcui/.cache/pre-commit/repoq7qnm1w0/py_env-python3.6/bin/python', '-mpip', 'install', '.')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout:
    Processing /Users/vcui/.cache/pre-commit/repoq7qnm1w0
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

stderr:
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /Users/vcui/.cache/pre-commit/repoq7qnm1w0/py_env-python3.6/bin/python /Users/vcui/.cache/pre-commit/repoq7qnm1w0/py_env-python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/9r/jcsx6jv923lb_fmm4w09zq5m0000gp/T/pip-build-env-wtkwct01/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'hatchling>=1.8.0' hatch-vcs hatch-fancy-pypi-readme
           cwd: None
      Complete output (2 lines):
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hatchling>=1.8.0 (from versions: 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.11.3, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.15.0, 0.16.0, 0.17.0, 0.18.0, 0.19.0, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.24.0, 0.25.0, 0.25.1)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for hatchling>=1.8.0
```

Has anyone seen this before and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modern hatchling does not support `python3.6` -- pip is unable to find one which matches your request because 3.6 support was dropped after 0.25.1

you can force a different language version (assuming you have that python installed) via `language_version` -- such as:

```yaml
    -   id: black
        language_version: python3.11
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit